# How can I combine my two regular expressions and save the results as variable?

Tags: php, regex

I get all the images with this

```
preg_match_all('!http://.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui' , $content , $matches);
```

and this is how i block all the image if it has a "bad word"

```
'/(list|of|bad|words)/i'
```

How can I combine them and save the result instead in variable instead of print_r?
My purpose is to delete from content all those images and produce the "clean" content.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you want to combine them? AND? OR? MAYBE?

Comment: @Andrea Spadaccini I would like them with and (i think). My purpose is to delete from content all those images. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might require some tweaking depending on how `$content` is formatted:

```
<?php
    $content = 'http://www.example.com/images/image001.jpg 
                http://www.example.com/images/image002.jpeg 
                http://www.example.com/images/list001.jpg 
                http://www.example.com/images/image003.png 
                http://www.example.com/images/bad002.png 
                http://www.example.com/images/image004.gif 
                http://www.example.com/images/words003.jpg';

    preg_match_all('!http://.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui', $content, $matches);

    preg_match_all('/\S+(list|of|bad|words)\S+/i', $content, $bads);

    $filtered = array_values(array_diff($matches[0], $bads[0]));

    print_r($filtered);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.example.com/images/image001.jpg
    [1] => http://www.example.com/images/image002.jpeg
    [2] => http://www.example.com/images/image003.png
    [3] => http://www.example.com/images/image004.gif
)
```

Comment: Thank you jnpcl! Please take a look at my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508151/a-specific-problem-with-my-script-that-includes-php-dom-and-regular-expressions

Answer (score 2):

Probably the fastest way is to run the first regex and then filter out the bad ones later. You could probably do this with a callback rather easily. I wouldn't try to combine the regex though.

Comment: Thank you for that. How can I save the "clean" content to a value and display the new content?