# A specific problem with my script that includes PHP, DOM and Regular Expressions

Tags: php, regex, dom

I am making a script that gets the content and images of blog posts using DOM and regular expressions.

The script is finished except the following. My aim is to get the content (it is done) all the post's images EXCEPT THE FIRST and add them to the new content with value varcontent1, 2, 3 and so on.

The script runs 25 times (the number of posts in page), and there is a variable `$i`.  The following code gets the current post content and saves it to `$varcontent1`.  Also it gets all the images of the whole site (with a list of bad words) and prints them as an array.

My question is how can I save the current images to the current post? Finally I will transform them to `<img src="xxxx">` (I think I know how to do it).

**UPDATED:** the results will be submitted to a form. What if I put the current images URLs to a new post variable?

Note: I can get the images with DOM because I load the page, not loadHTML.

```
preg_match_all('!http://.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui', $content, $matches);

    preg_match_all('/\S+(list|of|bad|words)\S+/i', $content, $bads);

    $filtered = array_values(array_diff($matches[0], $bads[0]));
```

Comment: Maybe: `${'varcontent' . $i} = $filtered[$i];`

Comment: @jnpcl But that means that it will get only 1 image right ? Oh I had an idea. The results will be submitted to a form. What if I save the current ones in a new post variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using offset...

```
preg_match_all('!http://.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui', $content, $matches, NULL, 1);
```

Don't use 1,2,3... use arrays...

```
$varcontent[$i]["content"] = $content;
$varcontent[$i]["images"] = array_unique($filtered);
```

When reading posts...

```
foreach($varcontent as $content){
    echo $content["content"]; // HTML or plain text
    foreach($content["images"] as $image){
         echo '<img alt="" src="'.$image.'"/>'; // All images
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post print_r result of $filtered?

Comment: You must paste outputs, no one can guess what is what. That's why no one else answered. $content is a string? I can't see what is there not be working. Just replace your `${'varcontent'.$i}` with my second code block and the `print_r($varcontent[$i]);`

Comment: Ok, double check everything, please :)

Comment: Updated it with another one array

Comment: I get a Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). I have changed 1 to `$i`

Comment: Hi webarto, I tried and got it working. Thanks. However it displays everything twice...

Comment: Work on it, you'll figure it out. Tick the green checkbox ;)

Comment: Actually is more than twice. I checked it, thanks webarto! If you have 5 more minutes for this it would be great

Comment: No problem, replace the second block again ;) Images are causing "problem"?

Comment: Images are working great! I have updated the question with the whole code and the sequenceof displaying posts.

Comment: And how can I save post 1 (content and images) as html into a var ?

Comment: Nooooo, you have double loop, remove "my" foreach, and put it right before `?>`. All posts are in $varcontent array, if you want first post just access $varcontent[0], try using print_r on it and you will se for yourself.

Comment: I am trying but I don't know which one... Can you edit the code please?

Comment: I can echo the content but not the images. It gives me the word array `for ($j=0;$j<=4;$j++){
echo $varcontent[$j]["content"];
echo $varcontent[$j]["images"];
}`

Comment: $varcontent[$j]["images"] is an array, so you must run a loop to iterate all images ($varcontent[$i]["images"][$j]), or like a did with foreach.

Comment: Don't use the `'U'` ungreedy regex modifier - it only serves to confuse! Instead add `?` to each quantifier you want to be lazy.

Comment: Instead of a dot, use \S (non-space). Otherwise you will get false matches of consecutive URLs, e.g. The regex above erroneously matches this whole string including both of these URLs (and the stuff in between): `http://abc.com/nonimg.txt foo bar http://abc.com/img.jpeg`

Comment: @ridgerunner something like this `#http://([^\s])+(\.(jpe?g|png|gif))#is`? I think `http://` needs to be there because in front of it is " (non-space) so it will match it also. He wants to extract URL from IMG tag. Thanks.

Comment: @webarto: Yes, the `http:` needs to be there. I was referring to just the dot in your expression. Note that: `\S` is the exact same thing as `[^\s]`. (i.e. `'\S'` means: "one _non-whitespace_ character")

Comment: I have copied his regex without testing it, thanks for the tips ;)